# Dimension with respect to a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This question has confused me. I appreciate anybody who can help or give a reference.

Let $R$ be a ring and $A$, $X$, and $M$  be $R$-modules. We say that a map $f:M\longrightarrow A$  is an *$X$-minimal right approximation* of $A$ provided $M\in\operatorname{add} X$, where $\operatorname{add} X$ denotes the class of all direct summands of a direct sum of copies of $X$, $f$ is minimal and any map from $X$ to $A$ factors through $f$. Let $X-\dim(A)$ denote the $X$-dimension of $A$ which is defined in terms of a minimal $X$-resolution of the module $A$, as for the case of projective dimension.

The question is:

> Is there any relation between $X\oplus Y-\dim(A)$, $X-\dim(A)$ and $Y-\dim(A)$ for arbitrary $X$, $Y$ and $A$?

Thank you all!